# Pulling incremental entries from an array in an each loop

Tags: jquery, this, each

I have an .each loop. For each itteration of the element I wish to add the incriment of an array to an atribute value. Can't get the sequential array value working though. Heres my code...

```
var accordionArray = []
$('a').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('acc-head')) {
        accordionArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
    }
}); //end a
$('div').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ready-accordion')) {
        $(this).attr('role', 'tab');
        $(this).attr('aria-labelledby', accordionArray[i]);
    }
}); //end div
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure it's something stupid that I'm just to close to it top see. Thanks

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What result are you getting and what result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a counter :

```
var counter = 0;
$('div').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ready-accordion')) {
        $(this).attr('role', 'tab');
        $(this).attr('aria-labelledby', accordionArray[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Didn't think about adding a seporate counter because .each has it's own. [slaps head] Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var accordionArray = []
$('a').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('acc-head')) {
        //accordionArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
        $('div.ready-accordian').eq(i).attr('aria-labelledby', $(this).attr('id'));
    }
}); //end a
```